# Bus Seating Arrangement same as in RedBus, Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a bus seat booking application which is very similar to RedBus app. I came across over the seating arrangement in that and i was struck over there.

I really need your help in achieving this. I have tried with Recycler View but that doesn't get me into the exact layout.

I have tried with recycler view and my layout goes as,

[image]

But, the actual screen shot from redbud application is as,

[image]

I have gone through one of the code that is available in git

https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/SeatBookingRecyclerView

But, using the above code, i can get the layout design but the problem with this is, **Say like if there are 41 seats, but using the above git code it will be showing 33 seats** on the screen comes up like as,

[image]

Help would be really appreciated.

Snippet Code:

```
     numOfColumns = 4;
     mArrayBusSeats = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mArraySeats.size(); i++) {
                if (i % numOfColumns == 0 || i % numOfColumns == (numOfColumns - 1)) {
                    BusLayoutModel model = mArraySeats.get(i);
                    model.setSeatType(AbstractItem.TYPE_EDGE);
                    mArrayBusSeats.add(model);
                } else if (i % numOfColumns == 1 || i % numOfColumns == (numOfColumns - 2)) {
                    BusLayoutModel model = mArraySeats.get(i);
                    model.setSeatType(AbstractItem.TYPE_CENTER);
                    mArrayBusSeats.add(model);
                } else {
                    BusLayoutModel model = new BusLayoutModel();
                    model.setSeatType(AbstractItem.TYPE_EMPTY);
                    mArrayBusSeats.add(model);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, your `recyclerview` has 3 `viewType`s - **`TYPE_EDGE, TYPE_CENTER, TYPE_EMPTY`**  i.e, seats are of 3 types. As in your question

> *Say like if there are 41 seats, but using the above git code it will be showing 33 seats*

Infact this is the expected behaviour since your `recyclerview` consists of a `viewtype` - **`TYPE_EMPTY`** which prints an empty view. So if you give `41 seats` only 33 will be visible since the rest of the seats are of type **`TYPE_EMPTY`** . If you count the empty positions in your `recyclerview` as well, then you can see that the total will be 41.

Comment: hmm, however, it's only 8 * 5 = 40, where is the last seats, since he said it's 41 (but i agree with your idea about empty space are seats that `viewType = TYPE_EMPTY`)

Comment: i didn't quite get your question, but let me explain - if the `mArraySeats.size()` is 41, it will render seats only upto 41 and hence the remaining positions will not be filled

Comment: `mArraySeats.size() = 41`, as Op stated in his question. What i mean is, including blank space in his screenshot, only 40 seats on screen

Comment: this screenshot clearly dont belong to the given code with `numOfColumns = 4;` since it is having 5 columns(including the `TYPE_EMPTY`) . Infact the code belong to his first screenshot where there is only 4 columns

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the number of column 5 ??

I haven't use the library but when I checked it I think I should be done like this

```
numOfColumns = 5;
     mArrayBusSeats = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mArraySeats.size(); i++) {

            BusLayoutModel model = mArraySeats.get(i);

                if (i % numOfColumns == 0 || i % numOfColumns == 4) {
                    model.setSeatType(AbstractItem.TYPE_EDGE);
                    mArrayBusSeats.add(model);
                } else if (i % numOfColumns == 1 || i % numOfColumns == 3) {
                    model.setSeatType(AbstractItem.TYPE_CENTER);
                    mArrayBusSeats.add(model);
                } else {
                    model.setSeatType(AbstractItem.TYPE_EMPTY);
                    mArrayBusSeats.add(model);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Recycler View implementation try to reduce row height, as compared to redbus your row height is almost double.